# How to find a String that startsWith other String in Map<String, String>, by the most efficient way

Tags: java, string, performance, dictionary

I collect a lot of String that is package name, and put these strings into the map as key, the value is alias of the key. (i chose TreeMap<String, String>)

like:

```
Map<String, String> packages = new TreeMap<>();
packages.put("org.springframework.boot.actuate", "SpringBoot@Actuate");
packages.put("org.springframework.boot.aop", "SpringBoot@AOP");
packages.put("org.apache.ibatis", "Mybatis@Core");
packages.put("org.mybatis.spring", "Mybatis@Spring");
packages.put("org.slf4j", "SLF4j@Core");
packages.put("ch.qos.logback.core", "Logback@Core");
```

then, the method parameter is specified value of fully-qualified Class name, i need return the value which alias(value) corresponds to the package(key)

like:

```
// className: ch.qos.logback.core.layout.EchoLayout
@Nullable
String find(String className) {
  // method implementation
  return ""; // return Logback@Core
}
```

i want to step-by-step lookup from the first level of package names using TreeMap.subMap(), and do it recursively

like:

```
// !!! pseudocode !!!
@Nullable
String find(String className, int position) {
  int idx = className.indexOf(".", position);
  String pkg = className.substring(0, idx);
  
  Map<String, String> sub = packages.subMap(pkg, pkg + " ");
  if (sub.size() == 1) {
    return ""; // found it
  } else {
    return ""; // other situations
  }

  return ""; // not found any alias
}
```

I'm not sure that's the most efficient way to do it, this method will be called frequently. can anyone offer a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd argue it would be simpler to start with the FQCN from the argument and remove one level from the end and check for the existence in the map at each level. FQCN can get pretty long but realistically you're looking at maybe 10-20 existence checks in the worst case. Also, if you choose this approach I would use HashMap instead of TreeMap so lookups are O(1).

Example Code:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
class Main {

  static Map<String, String> packages = new HashMap<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    packages.put("org.springframework.boot.actuate", "SpringBoot@Actuate");
    packages.put("org.springframework.boot.aop", "SpringBoot@AOP");
    packages.put("org.apache.ibatis", "Mybatis@Core");
    packages.put("org.mybatis.spring", "Mybatis@Spring");
    packages.put("org.slf4j", "SLF4j@Core");
    packages.put("ch.qos.logback.core", "Logback@Core");
    

    System.out.println(find("ch.qos.logback.core.layout.EchoLayout"));

  }

  // className: ch.qos.logback.core.layout.EchoLayout
  static String find(String className) {
  // method implementation

  List<String> classNameParts = Arrays.asList(className.split("\\."));

  // Checks for entries in the map in the following order
  // ch.qos.logback.core.layout.EchoLayout
  // ch.qos.logback.core.layout
  // ch.qos.logback.core
  // ch.qos.logback
  // ch.qos
  // ch
  for(int i = classNameParts.size(); i >= 0; i--){
      String packagePart = classNameParts.stream().limit(i).collect(Collectors.joining("."));
      if(packages.containsKey(packagePart)){
        return packages.get(packagePart);
      }
  }

  // No entry found
  return null;
}
}
```

Try it on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@FrankGreguska/PaltrySparseAddresses)

Comment: actually, it's better than my thinking. the function is fine, then i need to care of performance

Comment: actually, it is best approach.